# Getting this error in django "ModuleNotFoundError at /myapp/"

Tags: python, django, templates

I am using django version 11.3. I create a separate HTML template file and import in my views.py file when i run this file it gives me an error.

**ModuleNotFoundError at /myapp/**

**No module named 'django.templates'**

My settings.py file code:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.templates.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
    ,
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.templates.context_processors.debug',
            'django.templates.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

views.py file:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django .template import loader
from .models import album

def myapp(request):
  all_albums = album.objects.all()
  template = loader.get_template('myapp/index.html')
  context = {
   'all_albums': all_albums,
  }
  return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

 def detail(request, id):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Your requested numbers is: " + str(id) +"<h2>")
```

html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>This is list item</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    {% for a in all_albums %}
    <li><a href="/myapp/{{ a.id }}">{{ a.artist }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Directory structure:

```
myapp > templates > myapp > index.html
```

Comment: have you added the app to the installed_apps in the settings file?

Comment: yes  'myapp.apps.MyappConfig',

Comment: can you post  your stacktrace

Answer (score 3):

You must use `django.template` without the `s`:

```
TEMPLATES = [{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
}]`
```

Comment: so you are still using `django.templates` somewhere instead of `django.template`